# Edit mode selection doesn't highlight everything

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, selection-tools

I am having problem with imported mesh from newer version of blender. Then I select all vertices using A or L, it only highlights vertices in vertices selection mode, but doesn't highlight edges. How can I fix it?
[image]

Also in face selection mode it doesn't highlight whole face, only face selection points.
[image]

I am working in blender 2.79

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this overlays options in the N-Panel:

Blender 2.79
[image]

Blender 2.93
[image]